# Sound Localization with a single microphone

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I am trying to determine the direction of an audio signal using the microphone on an iPhone. Is there any way to do this? As far as I have read and attempted, it isn't possible. I have made extensive models with keras and even then determining the location of the sound is shaky at best due to the number of variables. So not including any ML aspects, is there a library or method to determine audio direction from an iOS microphone?

Comment: I don't really understand the downvotes/close here.  It's a fine question and appropriate for the platform--although Physics might be another good place for it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in general it shouldn't be possible (Even with machine learning)--you need at least two points (and excellent timing) to determine a direction.  You MIGHT be able to do something with multiple iPhones, but that would require very tight timing and some learning to determine where the phones are in relation to each other--and I doubt such a library already exists for the iPhone (existing libraries could be ported/adapted though)

Comment: Thank you, I completely agree but colleagues were suggesting it is somehow possible to do beamforming with a single microphone which I argued inherently isn't possible.

Comment: If you had the perfect room you might be able to time echos but it wouldn't be consistent and would have to "Learn" the layout of the room.  If the room didn't echo or was in the middle of a square room, it wouldn't work at all, if it did you would have to "Learn" which set of echos corresponded to which location and even then would be wrong more often than right.